# Get error 'run-time error -2147024894(80070002)'... when extract zip file

Tags: excel, vba, unzip

I have one archive file that contains multiple subfolders in it.

For example : `C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop\Macro\Intermediación Financiera\2013\12\BCO_Ind.zip`

In the **BCO_Ind.zip** contains this subfolder `scbm\2013\09\fileThatIWant.xls`

These subfolder are different for each archive file although it has the same name.
the things is i want the last file from the last subfolder.

I modified the code from http://excelexperts.com/unzip-files-using-vba and from www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win002.htm

The problem is I get an error which is:
`run-time error -2147024894(80070002)': Method 'Namespace' of Object 'IShellDispatch4' failed`.

I try to search all from the website but I didn't find the solution for almost a week.
Here is the code:

```
Sub TestRun()
'Change this as per your requirement
Call unzip("C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop\Macro\Intermediación Financiera\2013\12\", "C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop\Macro\Intermediación Financiera\2013\12\BCO_Ind.zip")
End Sub

Public Function unzip(targetpath As String, filename As Variant, Optional SCinZip As String, _
                    Optional excelfile As String) As String '(targetpath As String, filename As Variant)

Dim strScBOOKzip As String, strScBOOK As String:  strScBOOK = targetpath 
Dim targetpathzip As String, excelpath As String 
Dim bzip As Boolean: bzip = False
Dim oApp As Object
Dim FileNameFolder As Variant
Dim fileNameInZip As Object
Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim filenames As Variant: filenames = filename

If Right(targetpath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
   targetpathzip = targetpath & Application.PathSeparator
Else
   targetpathzip = targetpath
End If

FileNameFolder = targetpathzip
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
''-----i get an error in here
For Each fileNameInZip In oApp.Namespace(filenames).Items
  If objFSO.FolderExists(FileNameFolder & fileNameInZip) Then
    objFSO.DeleteFolder FileNameFolder & fileNameInZip, True: Sleep 1000
  End If
''-----i get an error in here too
  oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(filename).Items.item(CStr(fileNameInZip))
  bzip = True
Next fileNameInZip

If bzip Then
  excelpath = findexactfile(targetpath) ' this will go to the function that find the file from subfolders
Else
  excelpath = ""
End If
searchfolder = FileNameFolder & fileNameInZip

finish:
  unzip = excelpath
  Set objFSO = Nothing
  Set oApp = Nothing
End Function
```

I also tick some tools>references in development macro but it still get the same error. I really stress+frustrated right now. Please help me to fix it. Also, is there have a simple code as my references to find the file from subfolder after the file is extract? I really appreciate it if someone can share the code.

Comment: It may be easier to Copy all contents of the zip file to a temporary folder and use **objFSO** methods to copy desired file. What exactly you mean by `i want the last file from the last subfolder`? Do you mean you want the files in which the folder does not have subfolders?

Comment: Hi patrick...what I mean is the files that I want is in the last subfolder in the archive. The archive files (BCO_Ind.zip) contains this subfolder scbm\2013\09\**fileThatIWant.xls**    Thus, I want this file **fileThatIWant.xls**

Comment: so `fileThatIWant.xls` is the only file in the archive? Would there be  other subfolders like `scbm\2013\08\fileThatIWant.xls`? I was able to tweak you code to show files name in a zip file. Would you be using this to open more than 1 zip file at a time (all zip files from a main folder)?

Comment: hi patrick, there are no others subfolders in the archive file. Just these one only. The code is only using for one zip file at a time because after I unzip it, I will move the file that I want to another folder. Then, i'll delete all the unzip file.

Answer (score 0):

I have a VBA solution that:

From a root folder where all zip files are located, all files within the zip file are extracted without the path.

Then I modified it such that the first file within the zip file with the deepest path will be extracted to a pre-defined folder. This should meet your scenario.

```
Option Explicit

Const sEXT As String = "zip"
Const sSourceFDR As String = "C:\Debug" ' Folder that contains all the zip files
Const sTargetFDR As String = "C:\Test" ' Folder to store all the files within the zip

Dim oFSO As Object, oShell As Object
Dim oCopy As Object ' Comment out to extract all files without path

Sub StartUnzipAll()
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Debug.Print Now & vbTab & "StartUnzipAll() Started"

    UnZipFolder sTargetFDR, sSourceFDR

    ' Only copy the first file in deepest folder:
    ' Comment out If-Block to extract all files without path
    If Not oCopy Is Nothing Then
        oShell.Namespace(sTargetFDR & Application.PathSeparator).CopyHere oCopy
    End If

    Debug.Print Now & vbTab & "StartUnzipAll() Finished"
    Set oShell = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub UnZipFolder(sTgtFDR As String, sSrcFDR As String)
    Dim oFile As Variant, oFDR As Variant
    ' Process all files in sSrcFDR
    For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sSrcFDR).Files
        If oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile) = sEXT Then
            UnZipFile sTgtFDR, oFile.Path
        End If
    Next
    ' Recurse all sub folders in sSrcFDR
    For Each oFDR In oFSO.GetFolder(sSrcFDR).SubFolders
        UnZipFolder sTgtFDR, oFDR.Path
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub UnZipFile(sFDR As String, oFile As Variant)
    Dim oItem As Object
    For Each oItem In oShell.Namespace(oFile).Items
        ' Process files only (identified by "." in the name)
        If InStr(1, oItem.Name, ".", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "File """ & oItem.Name & """ in """ & oItem.Path & """"
            ' Comment out If-Block to extract all files without path
            If oCopy Is Nothing Then
                Set oCopy = oItem
            Else
                If UBound(Split(oItem.Path, Application.PathSeparator)) > UBound(Split(oCopy.Path, Application.PathSeparator)) Then
                    Set oCopy = oItem
                End If
            End If
            ' Uncomment to extract all files without path
            'Debug.Print "Extracting """ & oIem.Name & """ to """ & sFDR & """"
            'oShell.Namespace(sFDR & Application.PathSeparator).CopyHere oItem
        Else
            ' No file extension, Recurse into this folder
            UnZipFile sFDR, oItem.Path
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Hope this helps you out. Merry X'mas!

Answer (score 0):

Thank You so much Patrick!

Here is my code.. I do separately means that, I unzip that folder first and find the exact path for that file. This code I found from some of the website(forgot in which website) and I modified a bit according to my needs. Anyways, thank you so much for sharing. 
Here is the code:

```
 Public Function unzip(strScBOOK As String, strScBOOKzip As Variant, _
                    Optional SCinZip As String, Optional excelScfile As String) As Boolean

 Dim targetpathzip As Variant, excelpath As String, bUNZIP As Boolean: bUNZIP = False
 Dim oApp As Object
 Dim FileNameFolder As Variant
 Dim fileNameInZip As Variant
 Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject

 If Right(strScBOOK, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
    targetpathzip = strScBOOK & Application.PathSeparator
 Else
    targetpathzip = strScBOOK
 End If

 FileNameFolder = targetpathzip
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
 For Each fileNameInZip In oApp.Namespace(strScBOOKzip).Items
    If objFSO.FolderExists(FileNameFolder & fileNameInZip) Then
        objFSO.DeleteFolder FileNameFolder & fileNameInZip, True: Sleep 1000
    End If
    oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(strScBOOKzip).Items.item(CStr(fileNameInZip))
    bUNZIP = True
Next fileNameInZip

finish:
    unzip = bUNZIP
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing
End Function

Public Function findexactpathfile(refstrScBOOK As String, refstrScBOOKzip As Variant, SCinZip As String, excelScfile As String) As String

Dim objrootfolder As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim subfolder As Folder, sourcefile As Variant, excelfile As String
Dim rootfolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim fileNameInZip As Variant, filename As Variant, deleteZip As Variant
Dim oApp As Object
Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject

sourcefile = Left(refstrScBOOK, Len(refstrScBOOK) - 1)
If Right(refstrScBOOK, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
    sourcefile = refstrScBOOK
Else
    sourcefile = Left(refstrScBOOK, Len(refstrScBOOK) - 1)
End If

Set rootfolder = objrootfolder.GetFolder(sourcefile)
filename = findexcelinsubfolder(rootfolder, True, SCinZip)
If filename <> "" Then
    fileNameInZip = Trim(Split(filename, "\")(UBound(Split(filename, "\"))))
    sourcefile = refstrScBOOK
    excelfile = MoveandRenameFile(CStr(filename), CStr(sourcefile), CStr(fileNameInZip), excelScfile)
End If
If excelfile <> "" Then
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    For Each deleteZip In oApp.Namespace(CVar(refstrScBOOKzip)).Items
        If objFSO.FolderExists(sourcefile & deleteZip) Then
            objFSO.DeleteFolder sourcefile & deleteZip, True: Sleep 1000
        End If
    Next deleteZip
End If

finish:
    findexactpathfile = excelfile
    Set rootfolder = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing
End Function

Public Function findexcelinsubfolder(objFolder As Scripting.Folder, IncludeSubFolders As Boolean, _
                                SCinZip As String, Optional filename As Variant) As String

Dim fileItem As Scripting.File
Dim subfileItem As Scripting.Folder
Dim Fname As Variant
Dim strTEMP As String
IncludeSubFolders = True

For Each fileItem In objFolder.Files
    '---amend like ".xls" to excel file in direction path(obs file)
    If fileItem.Name Like "*" & SCinZip & "*.xls*" Then
        Fname = fileItem.Path
        IncludeSubFolders = False
        Exit For
    End If
Next fileItem

If IncludeSubFolders Then
    For Each subfileItem In objFolder.SubFolders
        Fname = findexcelinsubfolder(subfileItem, IncludeSubFolders, SCinZip, Fname)
        If Fname <> "" Then Exit For
    Next subfileItem
End If

finish:
    findexcelinsubfolder = Fname
    Exit Function
End Function

Function MoveandRenameFile(sourcepath As String, targetpath As String, excelname As String, excelfile As String) As String

    Dim fso As Object

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fso.FileExists(targetpath & excelfile) Then
    '---delete the file, move and rename in the targetpath
        fso.DeleteFile targetpath & excelfile, True: Sleep 1000
        Name sourcepath As targetpath & excelfile
    Else
    '---move and rename in the targetpath
        Name sourcepath As targetpath & excelfile
    End If

finish:
    MoveandRenameFile = targetpath & excelfile
    Set fso = Nothing
End Function
```